# What's so special about the Bartenura on Mishnayos?

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, mishna, bartenura

Nowadays there are many peirushim that have been written on Mishnayis that are written clearly with full details and attention to all facets of understanding the mishna. Why is it that some people still feel that one has to learn "the Rav" (Bartenura) when learning a mishna just because that's the way it's been done for a few hundred years? Why isn't using the Artscroll Mishnayis or Siyayta Dishmaya Mishnayis which is much clearer and much more detailed than the Rav, more accepted and learned by Orthodox Jews?

Comment: "Why is it that some people still feel that one has to learn "the Rav" (Bartenura) when learning a mishna just because that's the way it's been done for a few hundred years?" Can you cite that this is the case?

Comment: Why don't you ask those people? What does this have to do with Judaism?

Comment: i read somewhere that the bartenura's commentary is the most "zach" (pure).

Comment: Is this unique to the Bartenura on Mishnayos? It seems like the question can be distilled to "Why do people study the classic commentaries where there are newer commentaries that seem clearer to understand (for whatever reason, i.e. language barrier, consolidation of various sources, etc)?"

Comment: While I do see Art Scroll as valuable to those that have trouble understanding Hebrew, I have always felt that, in General, Art Scroll, has in a sense, made capable learners "lazy". It's a given that much gets lost in translation, and there is nothing like trying to understand the original meaning of the original language of the Talmud. Art Scroll has a tendency to over-condense the translation and many that rely on it have avoided looking at the original sources b/c A.S. has done much of that work for you. Besides questioning A.S's merits, I question if it really is "mainstream" as you imply.

Comment: Bartenura is also a formidable halachist. He is brought many times Halacha limaaseh in teshuvos. Igros Moshe especially comes to mind as having quoted him lihalacha.

Answer (score 5):

Artscroll and Siata dishmaya are themselves using the Bartenura. Bartenura is concise, cover the Shass from  brachot to  Uktsim. is based mainly on Rashi and Rambam  perushim.   Is known as mastering the sugia. Had been studied beyun and accredited by  Tosfot Yom Tov,  Mel'echet Shlomo,  Rabbi Akiva Eiger, Tif'eret Israel and all acharonim. If you have a question about Bartenura you can compare your reflection with the reflection of the acharonim.

E. g.  Kehati does not help if you have a deep question,  generally he  avoided it intentionally because he is concerned by beginning level only. To appreciate the value of Tif'eret Israel,  Siata Dishmaya,  Tosfot Yom Yov,  Bet David,  Shoshanim Ledavid, Kol Haramaz,  Hon Ashir,  Mel'echet Shlomo,  Rashash,  Lechem Shamaym,  Ets Chayim,,   Nezirut Shimshon,  etc, you need to know on what they referred.

Learning with basic classic  perushim on mishnayot is learning talmudic rational thinking,  learning how to build a Suggia. How to develop reasoning without digression and with strong logic associations. For this you need the help of the way of yun ("סולם ניצב ארצה וראשו מגיע השמימה") which begins by reading and thinking with Bartenura.

Comment: +1 (what happened to you?) We want you back!!!

Comment: I can not believe this (the reason that "not masochist enough"), can I help that not happen again?

Comment: I wish you hatzolo rabba, you are probably doing correctly the shmini ... Of gaiva , (but maybe also keep in mind "student of Aron love peace ....")

Answer (score 1):

see- [http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/3171-bertinoro-obadiah-yareh-b-abraham]
- an article written by (Rabbi?) Louis Ginzberg and I quote (from paragraph titled "Literary Activity")-

"Its excellence lies in the fact that he selected the best afforded by Rashi and Maimonides and gave this in clear and easily comprehensible fashion."